# How to increase delivery trucks

Tags: prison-architect

So I've played prison architect for a long time but had a long break between a few alphas ago and the current version.  I just got back into it and made a really successful prison.

After playing for a while, I decided to mess around and see what the game was capable of.  Doing this I decided to create a prison purely of forestry rooms.  Each forestry is 64x32 and produces an insane amount of lumber.  In the screenshot you can see I have 5 of these setup.

Some would think the workers and gardeners to maintain it would be the limiting issue, but the issue I'm having is the delivery trucks.  The forestries produce so much wood, that my export zones are completely filling up.  And the rate of the trucks isn't increasing.

It seems the truck comes at a fixed rate.  Is there a way to change this rate to make them arrive more often?  Or is there any method of doing this at all?

*I'm willing to change my prison config file to fix this if that is an option*

Excuse the fact that I took the screenshot at night.

[image: Prsion]

```
 Pink   - Forestries
 Orange - Exports
 Red    - Truck
```

Comment: Although this world isn't in sandbox mode I would be willing to change my config settings.

Comment: I figured out the solution, or at least a temporary fix  you can keep doing.  You can manually sell all the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

There was a backlog I guess of queued trucks.  And in order to clear this, I had to manually sell all the logs.  After doing this a bunch of trucks just drove by on the screen all backlogged.

I do not know how permanent this solution is but for now it has fixed it for me.

[image: Trucks]

Comment: It wasn't permanent because since then they've "fixed" it in that there's one truck per hour when you only have exports.  When you get stuff delivered you get more trucks, obviously, but also only once per hour.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Since more than one truck can be loaded at a time make sure your Export area is long (tall) enough to accommodate more than one truck. Also leave a couple of squares space between the loading/unloading areas to make sure the trucks don't  queue up waiting to get in the correct position to load/unload.

The other factor is the number of workmen you have available at any time. Workmen are responsible for (among other things):

- loading and unloading trucks
- chopping down trees
- moving logs to the Export areas

You don't say how many workmen you have, but with insufficient staff to load/unload your trucks will stack up; even with the drivers to help.

Check your Job list to see which particular jobs are stacking up, that should help you decide if you need more workmen.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at hand: how can more trucks be made to arrive? In my experience, if the delivery/export/garbage/prisoner trucks don't have space, they form a queue. The OP claims that only one delivery truck is being sent.